# How to test CSS values in Python using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, flask, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I'm trying to test the video dimensions using the values in CSS as shown in the image below.

[image: html]

The CSS is being used by the Div below. The below is what I've done so far and the error I get.

```
def test_video_dimensions(browser):

browser.get(url_for("main.index", _external=True) + "video/title1/?video-height=500&video-width=750")

rows = browser.find_elements(
    By.XPATH, "/html/head/style[2]"
)
assert (
    rows[0].find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/head/style[2]").text
    == "CSS Value"
)
```

[image]

Any help to access the inside of the CSS style tag and compare the values in it?

Comment: when you write `.text` it is going to give you text between tags right ? Now what is  == "CSS Value" ? Is it like you wanna get css value of the mentioned web element ?

Comment: @cruisepandey What I basically want is, The page Div adapts to the video width and height I give. The only place the values are visible is inside the Style Tag under video-dimensions. I want to assert the value of width which is 760 px to the value I give which is also 760.

Comment: You can probably go to dev tools - (by pressing F12) then -> elements -> do ctrl +f -> and then search this `//style[@class= 'vjs-styles-dimensions']` and see if it's getting highlighted or not.

Comment: Yes it does get highlighted when i do that @cruisepandey

Comment: and I believe there's 1/1 entry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code :

```
some_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//style[2]").get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(some_value)
```

**output :**

```
.video-dimensions {
        width: 300px;
        height: 168.75px;
      }

      .video-dimensions.vjs-fluid {
        padding-top: 56.25%;
      }
```

Now if you just want to get width value probably the below code should work for you  :

```
some_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//style[2]").get_attribute('innerHTML').strip()
arr = some_value.split(":")
ar = arr[1].split(";")
print(ar[0])
```

or

```
some_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//style[2]").get_attribute('innerHTML').strip()
arr = some_value.split(":")[1].split(";")[0]
print(arr)
```

should print `300px` in this case.

Comment: I tried the 1st option for the Div tag as follows but still the same error.

`  assert (
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]").value_of_css_property('video-dimensions')
        == "Any value"
    ) `

E       AssertionError: assert '' == 'Any value'

Comment: Do not do assert as of now..just try to print `browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]").value_of_css_property('video-dimensions')` and see what you get

Comment: The value is null.

Comment: can you try with this `//style[@class= 'vjs-styles-dimensions']` ? like `browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//style[@class= 'vjs-styles-dimensions']").value_of_css_property('video-dimensions')`

Comment: Still it's null. gives an empty value

Comment: Is URL public ?

Comment: or you may want to try the second solution `i.e element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('your xpath here')
 properties = driver.execute_script('return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], null);', element)` and print like this `for property in properties:
    print(element.value_of_css_property(property))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234098/discussion-between-ashene-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: @Ashene : Check out the above code, I got busy with other stuff. Let me know if that works for you.